# How to get list of all AWS EC2 instances with specific tag and their utilisation of CPU and RAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am struggling to make the command to retrieve list of all AWS EC2 instances with specific tags and their CPU and RAM utilization.
Can someone help me with that ?

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{Name: Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0], Role: Tags[?Key==`Billing by Role`].Value | [0]}' --output text
```

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{Name: Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0], Role: Tags[?Key==`Billing by Role`].Value | [0]}' --output text
```

It gives me list of all the instances but not sure for utilization.

Comment: I think you have to use the cloudwatch metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get these metrics from cloudwatch, so get all the instance with tag first then run the loop to get stats of each instance.

```
#!/bin/bash
filter="prod"
AWS_INSTANCE_WITH_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=tag:Name,Values="${filter}"  --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]" --output text)

for instance_id in $AWS_INSTANCE_WITH_ID
    do
    # Now get CPU against instance ID from cloud metrics one by one against that tag
    aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name CPUUtilization --start-time 2019-09-12T23:18:00Z --end-time 2019-09-13T23:18:00Z --period 3600 --namespace AWS/EC2 --statistics Maximum --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=$instance_id
    done
```

Amazon CloudWatch retains metric data as follows:

> Data points with a period of less than 60 seconds are available for 3
>   hours. These data points are high-resolution metrics and are available
>   only for custom metrics that have been defined with a
>   StorageResolution of 1. Data points with a period of 60 seconds
>   (1-minute) are available for 15 days. Data points with a period of 300
>   seconds (5-minute) are available for 63 days. Data points with a
>   period of 3600 seconds (1 hour) are available for 455 days (15
>   months).

[Get-metric-statistics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to capture the RAM Utilization from the instances ?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html